# Send SMS Nexmo from Azure Function got error

Tags: c#, azure-functions, vonage

```
I try to send the SMS from Azure Function, it show the error. But if i do in Web or console app the sms succesfully sent. The error is this:
```

System.TypeInitializationException:'The type initializer for 'Nexmo.Api.Configuration' threw an exception.'

MissingMethodException:
Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.MemoryConfigurationBuilderExtensions.AddInMemoryCollection(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2>)'.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var client = new Nexmo.Api.Client(creds: new Credentials(Api_KEY, Api_Secret));
                var results = client.SMS.Send(request: new SMS.SMSRequest()
                {
                    from = nexmo.Sender,
                    text = nexmo.Msg,
                    to = nexmo.Receiver
                });
```

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project. Is it based on V1 or V2

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, it seems that the Nexmo.Csharp.Client package does not work correctly on Azure Functions.  This could be because one of the assemblies is not compatible with Azure (not all are) or some configuration setting that is not supported on Azure Functions.

I was surprised by how many references/assemblies are installed by:

Install-Package Nexmo.Csharp.Client

So I gave up on trying to identify what is the cause.  Instead a much simpler solution is to create your own HttpClient and use the REST API directly (that is probably what the weighty package does anyhow).

```
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", "YOURKEY"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_secret", "YOURSECRET"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("to", "TO!!!"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("from", "MisterCook"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", "MisterCook Says Hi")

        });

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
            "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json",
            requestContent);

        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
            // If you need it... 
        }
```

This will spare you from deploying the bulky Nexmo.Csharp.Client package deployment and works in Azure Functions.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old question, but I noticed it's still not had an answer accepted.

I've just used the latest version of the .Net SDK (5.9.0) with Functions v1, v3 and v4 using the below code and had no issues

```
using Vonage;
using Vonage.Request;
using Vonage.Messaging;

var credentials = Credentials.FromApiKeyAndSecret("abcd123efg", "abcdefgfgfgfgf");

 var VonageClient = new VonageClient(credentials);
 var response = VonageClient.SmsClient.SendAnSms(new SendSmsRequest()
 {
     To = "0123456789",
     From = "Vonage APIs",
     Text = "A text message sent using the Vonage SMS API"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works locally or in another context, then the code is correct. For Azure Functions in particular I would check that the dependencies are installed as you expect, and that the variables like API key have the values you expect (add some logging to test this) - these work differently in the serverless context. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also was able to get the new WhatsApp API running with Mister Cook's approach.

```
public bool Send(Message msg)
    {
        var task = SendAsync(msg);
        task.Wait();
        return task.Result;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendAsync(Message msg)
    {
        var requestJson = CreateJson(msg);
        Console.WriteLine(requestJson);
        var content = new StringContent(requestJson);
        content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
        var client = new HttpClient();            

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://messages-sandbox.nexmo.com/v0.1/messages", content);
            string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return MessageSucceeded(responseJson);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string CreateJson(Message msg)
    {
        JObject request = new JObject();
            JObject from = new JObject();
                from.Add("type", "whatsapp");
                from.Add("number", "14157386170");
            request.Add("from", from);


            JObject to = new JObject();
                to.Add("type", "whatsapp");
                to.Add("number", ConnectionData);
            request.Add("to", to);

            JObject message = new JObject();
                JObject content = new JObject();
                    content.Add("type", "text");
                    content.Add("text", msg.Text);
                message.Add("content", content);
            request.Add("message", message);
        return request.ToString();
    }

    private bool MessageSucceeded(string json)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken token;
        return obj.TryGetValue("message_uuid", out token);
    }
```

The RequestJson for Sandbox Testing is:

```
{ 
    "from": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "14157386170" }, 
    "to": { "type": "whatsapp", "number": "YOUR_WHITELIST_NUMBER" }, 
    "message": { 
        "content": { "type": "text", "text": "Test succeeded. Congrats" }
    }
}
```

If the Request succeeded, the ResponseJson will contain a message_uuid. I only check wether it is contained or not

```
{"message_uuid": "e6859d67-1a94-44c4-bf09-a3e3fa7f8691"}
```